# Can I pipe into a switch statement stored in a variable?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, scriptblock

I have a variable that stores a switch statement

```
$com = '
switch ($_)
{
    1 {"It is one."}
    2 {"It is two."}
    3 {"It is three."}
    4 {"It is four."}
}
'
```

I am trying to pipe in the number to run the switch statement

something like:

`1 | iex($com)`

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

1. A [`scriptblock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2) or [`function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) with a [`process` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#process):

```
$com = {
    process {
        switch ($_) {
            1 { "one."   }
            2 { "two."   }
            3 { "three." }
        }
    }
}

function thing {
    process {
        switch ($_) {
            1 { "one."   }
            2 { "two."   }
            3 { "three." }
        }
    }
}

1..3 | & $com
1..3 | thing
```

2. A [`filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2#filters), exactly the same functionality:

```
filter thing {
    switch ($_) {
        1 { "one."   }
        2 { "two."   }
        3 { "three." }
    }
}

1..3 | thing
```

3. Using [`ScriptBlock.Create` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.create?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) (this would require a `process` block in the string expression):

```
$com = '
process {
    switch ($_) {
        1 { "one."   }
        2 { "two."   }
        3 { "three." }
    }
}
'

1..3 | & ([scriptblock]::Create($com))
```

4. Using [`ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and the [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input), this technique **does not stream** and also requires an outer `scriptblock` to work, it's just to showcase and should be discarded as an option:

```
$com = '
switch ($_) {
    1 { "one."   }
    2 { "two."   }
    3 { "three." }
}
'

1..3 | & { [scriptblock]::Create($com).InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', $input)) }
```

5. Using [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3), also requires an outer `scriptblock` with a `process` block (should be discarded - from all techniques displayed above this is the worst one, the string expression is being evaluated per item passed through the pipeline):

```
$com = '
switch ($_) {
    1 { "one."   }
    2 { "two."   }
    3 { "three." }
}
'

1..3 | & { process { Invoke-Expression $com } }
```